# Xamarin.Android to Xamarin.Ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

About 6 months ago, I started to build an application using xamarin. To be honest, I have not given attention to xamarin.forms. Now that I have completed my android application using xamarin.android.

Now I want to make an Ios application for the same product. What are my options to convert my this android application to IOS so that I use the minimum amount of time and effort?

Please explain what are my options now?

Comment: There is no magic bullet.  If you designed your app to separate the UI/platform specific pieces from the core functions, you should be able to port the core code to either iOS or Forms, and then just re-write the UI.

Comment: Everywhere you used Android specific stuff you are pretty much stuck to rewriting it in a shared class I think (if its even possible). Try to discover classes that dont use any of the Xamarin.Android references. You should probably be able to extract those to a shared class library that you can reuse in an iOS project.

Comment: As Jason said, the Xamarin.Forms application is still needed first, and then the application with both iOS and Android platforms can be implemented....